# something wrong with the calculateWeeklypay methods of each employees

Tags: java

well i have now four types of employees. Managers (who receive a fixed weekly salary), Design workers (who receive a fixed hourly wage for up to the first 40 hours they work and "time-and-a-half," i.e., 1.5 times their hourly wage, for overtime hours worked), Sales workers (who receive a $250 plus 5.7% of their gross weekly sales), and  Manufacturing (who receive a fixed amount of money per item for each of the items they produce -- each manufacture in this company works on only one type of item).  and here are my classes:
employee class
the problem is i get this output:

```
You chose to open this file: Employees.txt
John Smith Manufacturing 6.75 120 444
0.0
Betty White Manager 1200.0 0 111
0.0
Stan Slimy Sales 10000.0 0 332
250.0
Betty Boop Design 12.5 50 244
0.0
```

meaning that it is getting 0 for all my calculations and leading to this weekly report:

```
WEEKLY PAY REPORT FOR Wacky Widgets COMPANY
Employee
0
    WEEKLY PAY 
250
Total Payroll: $0.0
Total number of managers paid:1
Total number of Design Employees paid:1
Total number of Sales Employees paid:1
Total number of Manufacturing Employees paid:1
```

i need help with fixing my methods so they can accept the integers of the file and use them in the calculation since all i'm getting at the moment are 0 values. i can provide my read-file method if it is need . thanks

here is the abstract class from which all the other employees type are extending from
[code]

```
public abstract class Employee {

    public abstract double calculateWeeklyPay();

    private String fName;
    private String lName;

    private int EmpId;
    private Position p; 
    /*
       public Employee()
       {

       }*/

    /**
     * default constructor
     */

    public Employee() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        /*this.getFName();
        this.getLName();
        this.getEmpId();*/
        getFName();
        getLName();
        this.getEmpId();
    }


    /**
     * @param string  first name
     * @param string2 last name
     * @param y       position
     */
    public Employee(String string, String string2, String y) {


        fName = string;
        lName = string2;
        // EmpId=string3;
        if (y.equals("Design")) {
            p = Position.Design;
        }
        if (y.equals("Sales")) {
            p = Position.Sales;
        }
        if (y.equals("Manufacturing")) {
            p = Position.Manufacturing;
        }
        if (y.equals("Manager")) {
            p = Position.Manager;
        }
        //  StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(fName+ lName+y,": .");

    }


    /**
     * @return first name
     */
    public String getFName() {
        return fName;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName sets the first name
     */
    public void setFName(String firstName) {
        this.fName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return last name
     */
    public String getLName() {
        return lName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName
     */
    public void setLName(String lastName) {
        this.lName = lastName;
    }

    /*public String toString()
    {

    //  String str =  firstName+" "+lastName+" "+"Position: "+getPosition();
        return firstName;
        }*/

    /**
     * @return p position
     */
    public Position getPosition() {

        //  String str =  firstName+" "+lastName+" "+"Position: "+getPosition();
        return p;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = fName + " " + lName + " " + "Position: " + getPosition();
        return str;

    }//https://www.udemy.com/blog/java-abstract-class/


    public int getEmpId() {
        return EmpId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.EmpId = empId;
    }

}
```

design employee class

```
public class Design extends Employee {
    public double rate;//rate for each hours
    public double h;//hours worked

    public Design(String fName, String lName, String pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        //double firstParam, int secondParam, int empNum
        super(fName, lName, pos);
        //toString();

        calculateWeeklyPay();
    }

    @Override
    public double calculateWeeklyPay() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double weeklyPay = 0;
        if (h <= 40) {
            weeklyPay = h * rate;
        }
        if (h > 40) {
            h = h * (3 / 2);
            weeklyPay = h * rate;
        }
        //System.out.println(weeklyPay);
        return weeklyPay;
    }

    public double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public double getH() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(double h) {
        this.h = h;
    }

}
```

sales employee

```
 public class Sales extends Employee {

    private double weekSales;
    private final double pay = 250;
    private final double percent = .057;


    public Sales(String fName, String lName, String pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(fName, lName, pos);


        this.calculateWeeklyPay();
    }

    @Override
    public double calculateWeeklyPay() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double weekPay;
        weekPay = pay + percent * this.getWeekSales();
        return weekPay;
    }

    public double getWeekSales() {
        return weekSales;
    }

    public void setWeekSales(double weekSales) {
        this.weekSales = weekSales;
    }

}
```

and i have two other employee type of classes but they won't be needed here since if i fix the problem in this one class i can fix the others.
here's is my company class which reads a file a calculates the weekly pay and total weekly pay of all employees classes

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Company implements CompanyInterface {
    //private Employee addEmp = new Employee();
    //  private Position addPosition = new 
    private ArrayList<Employee> list;
    private static int numberOfCompanies;
    private String CompanyName;
    private int numDesign;
    private int numEmployees;
    private int numManufacturing;
    private int numManager;
    private int numSales;
    /*String fName="";
    String lName="";
    String position="";
    String first="";
    String second="";
    String empID="";
    Scanner File;*/
    //private ArrayList<Employee> list2 ;
    private Employee addEmp;

    /**
     * @param cn is the company name
     */
    public Company(String cn) {

        cn = "Wacky Widgets";
        list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        numDesign = 0;
        numEmployees = 0;
        numManufacturing = 0;
        numSales = 0;

        numberOfCompanies++;
        setCompanyName(cn);

    }

    @Override
    /**
     * @param fName first name
     * @param lName last name
     * @param pos position
     * @return null if everything is right
     */


    public String addEmployee(String fName, String lName, String pos,
                              double firstParam, int secondParam, int empNum) {
        String message = null;
        //  if (pos.equals("DESIGN")&&       

        numDesign == 1 && numSales != 2 && numManufacturing != 4)
        if (pos.equals("Design")) {

            if (numDesign == 2)//p2=Position.DESIGN;
            {

                message = "There are already 2 design persons\nEmployee not          
                added ";

            } else {
                addEmp = new Design(fName, lName, pos);
                numDesign++;
                numEmployees++;
                list.add(addEmp);
            }


        }//else return message;
        //if (pos.equals("SALES")&&numDesign<1&&numSales<2&&numManufacturing<4)
        else if (pos.equals("Sales")) {
            if (numSales == 1) {
                message = "There is already a sales person\nEmployee not    
                added ";


            } else {
                //p2=Position.SALES;
                addEmp = new Sales(fName, lName, pos);
                numSales++;
                numEmployees++;
                list.add(addEmp);
            }

        }//else return message;
        else if (pos.equals("Manufacturing")) {
            if (numManufacturing == 4) {
                message = "There are already four manufacturing persons     
                \nEmployee not added ";
            } else {
                //p2=Position.MANUFACTURING;
                addEmp = new Manufacturing(fName, lName, pos);
                numManufacturing++;
                numEmployees++;
                list.add(addEmp);
            }
        } else if (pos.equals("Manager")) {
            if (numManager == 1) {
                message = "There is already a manager person\nEmployee not 
                added ";
            } else {
                //p2=Position.MANUFACTURING;
                addEmp = new Manufacturing(fName, lName, pos);
                numManager++;
                numEmployees++;
                list.add(addEmp);
            }
        }
        //String str=fName+" "+lName+" "+pos+" "+firstParam+" "+empNum;
        System.out.println(fName + " " + lName + " " + pos + " " + firstParam + " " + secondParam + " 
                "+empNum);
                //firstParam=Employee.
                System.out.println(calculateTotalWeeklyPay());

        return message;

    }

    /**
     * Returns number of companies
     *
     * @return number of companies
     */
    public static int getNumCompanies() {
        return numberOfCompanies;
    }

    public void setNumCompanies(int nc) {
        numberOfCompanies = nc;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the number of employees
     *
     * @param ne number of employees
     */
    public void setNumemployees(int ne) {
        numEmployees = ne;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of employees
     *
     * @return the number of employees
     */
    public int getNumEmployees() {
        return numEmployees;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumManager() {

        return numManager;
    }

    /**
     * sets the number of designer
     *
     * @param nd number of designer
     */
    public void setNumDesign(int num) {
        numDesign = num;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumDesign() {

        return numDesign;
    }

    public void setNumsales(int num) {
        numSales = num;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumSales() {

        return numSales;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the number of manufacturer
     *
     * @param nm the number of manufacturer
     */
    public void setNumManufacturing(int num) {
        numManufacturing = num;
    }

    @Override

    public int getNumManufacturing() {

        return numManufacturing;
    }

    public void setNumManager(int num) {
        numManager = num;
    }

    @Override
    public String generateWeeklyReport() {

        int empID = 0;
        String title = "WEEKLY PAY REPORT FOR " + getCompanyName() + " COMPANY" + "\n";
        String label = "Employee\n";
        String label2 = "WEEKLY PAY \n";
        int payWeek = 0;

        double total = 0.0;

        for (Employee index : list) {

            empID += index.getEmpId();
            payWeek += index.calculateWeeklyPay();

        }

        return title + label + empID + "\n" + "\t" + label2 + payWeek + "\n" + "Total Payroll: 


        $ "+total+"\n "+
        "Total number of managers paid:" + getNumManager() + "\n" +
                "Total number of Design Employees paid:" + getNumDesign() + "\n" +
                "Total number of Sales Employees paid:" + getNumSales() + "\n" +
                "Total number of Manufacturing Employees paid:" + getNumManufacturing();
    }

    @Override
    public double calculateTotalWeeklyPay() {

        double total = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
            total = list.get(index).calculateWeeklyPay();
            //total.add(list.get(index).calculateWeeklyPay());


        }
        return total;
    }


    /**
     * @return str the arraylist of employees and positions
     */

    public String printCompany() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "";
        for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
            str += list.get(index).getFName() + " " + list.get(index).getLName() + " 
            "+" Position:
            "+list.get(index).getPosition()+"\n ";

        }//System.out.println(str);
        return str;


    }

    /**
     * @return company name
     */
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return CompanyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        //companyName="Wacky Widgets";
        this.CompanyName = companyName;
    }


    public String toString() {
        //  int i =0;
        String str = CompanyName + "";
        //String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            str += "\n" + list.get(i).getFName() + " " + list.get(i).getLName() + " 
            "+" Position:
            "+list.get(i).getPosition()+"\n ";
        }


        return str;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please give a minimal example for the problem, and fix the formatting of  the question.

Answer (score 0):

This stands out:

```
h = h * (3 / 2);
```

You're doing integer division here, so you're always multiplying by 1, effectively.

Change that to use floating-point values instead.

```
h = h * (3.0 / 2);
```

Alternatively, be explicit about what you're multiplying by - you know it's always time and a half, so I see no reason not to do this:

```
h = h * 1.5;
```